# Transform new column with counts of items in a row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame with items separated with commas. I would like to transform a new column with the counts of each items within a row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [['one', 'two', 'three' ],
                          ['four', 'five', 'six', 'seven']
                         ]})
```

[image]

for the first row I would like to return 3, and the next 4 and transform a new column. I tried:

```
df.A[0].count(',') + 1
```

That would give me a count of the first row, but how do I transform a new column with the counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to go is essentially create a list of the values that you want, and assign it to this new column.

This could be done using list comprehension like this:

```
# This will assign the lengths of the lists to a column called 'count'
df['count'] = [len(l) for l in df['A']]
```

You can also use pandas' own `apply` method, either directly to the Series:

```
df['count'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

Or applied across the whole row, which would allow you to access the values from other columns if you desired:

```
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(x['A']), axis=1)
```

As your attempt shows you counting commas, I assume that the values in the columns are strings, rather than lists. I would check that this is the intended behaviour, and if not convert the strings into lists.
If you do just want to do a count of the commas, you could apply your methods like so:

```
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.A.count(',') + 1, axis=1)
```